# Amazon AWS S3 deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've a problem using amazon AWS S3 for publish static web page, I need publish this template on amazon S3 (https://gogo-react.coloredstrategies.com/), deploy process was publish successfully http://ifactum-events-test.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ but when I click on option **View Now**, the next message is shown on webpage:

```
Code: 404 Not Found NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: app
```

I don't know how is possible to link to this page using deploy or bucket policy.

Comment: It seems like it's working now

Comment: Have you setup both both index document and error document to home router, like `index.html` ?